# Integrate a React Native app in to an existing iOS Obj-C/Swift App

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-ios.html#content

This facebook guide and other resources online seem to have the same current implementation guidelines. Something that seems pretty insane, and not something I'm looking to do for my `react-native` app.

Basically, my goal is to create a simple `react-native` app in a separate repo and dev space, build/bundle the JS in to the `main.jsbundle` file and have my current iOS application pull that script and use it on deployments.

In this case, all that is required in my old codebase is a simple wrapper function that launches the `react-native` app when requested, otherwise functionality acts as it has always done.

It seems pretty weird to me that people would want to write both types of code inside a single codebase, and that is not my goal.

Has anyone got any insight in to how I would accomplish this task?

My project dirs should look something like this:

`iOS/
    Project.xcodeproj
    Project/
        AppDelegate.m
    main.jsbundle
React-Native/
    iOS/
        AppDelegate.m
    index.ios.js`

The `main.jsbundle` in `iOS/` is simply the generated bundle from the `react-native` project.

Answer (score 0):

There's an "integration with existing app" in the official doc. Looks like the way to go : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

You should be able to build the bundle outside of your iOS main project and import it later in the process. Everything should be quite easily automated.

https://apphub.io could be also a great solution. They're a a commercial service but also have an opensource self-hostable server.

edit : 
MS Codepush (part of appcenter) is a great tool as well.